# PostgreSQL - Completing a Series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a series, and here is a simple formula, where x = yesterday, and y = three days ago:

```
x + (x - y) / 2
```

In excel, computing the above series is easy.  But here is a sample data set in which I would like to complete a series based off of previous values.  Please note, that the actual data simply comes from the data set.  So we have data from 1/1/2018, 1/2/2018, and 1/3/2018.  We would then like to predict 1/4/2018 through 1/8/2018 based on the above formula:

```
      A (dt)    B (sum)   excel equivalent
row1  1/1/2018  1         (actual)
row2  1/2/2018  2         (actual)
row3  1/3/2018  5         (actual)
row4  1/4/2018  7         (predicted) =B3 + ((B3 - B1) / 2)
row5  1/5/2018  9.5       (predicted) =B4 + ((B4 - B2) / 2)
row6  1/6/2018  11.75     (predicted) =B5 + ((B5 - B3) / 2)
row7  1/7/2018  14.125    (predicted) =B6 + ((B6 - B4) / 2)
row8  1/8/2018  16.4375   (predicted) =B7 + ((B7 - B5) / 2)
```

I know that that you achieve a cumulative sum by using Partition By, however I am having trouble with modified cumulative sums, such as the above.  Is there a way to  accomplish this in PostgreSQL?

Here is a screenshot of excel:

[image]

Comment: Where does this `(actual)` come from? Please share some sample data and your desired results.

Comment: Actual data comes from the data set, I will update my question for clarity

Comment: So `y` is actually **3** days (rows) before the current row, no?

Comment: Yes I made another update, x = yesterday and y = 3 days ago.  This is just a sample, y could = any number of days ago.

Comment: I think you can use `lag()`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I think it's going to be more complicated. This is more like a lag + cumulative sum issue. Makes perfect sense when you see your data from an excel perspective. Makes much less sense when viewing it from a relational viewpoint.

Comment: I've tried lag, however where I get lost is updating and completing a series.  For example, I am unable to calculate a number from row7 (the calculated number) using lag.

Comment: @Mike Right. That's the "Cumulative" part, but it means the lag() and calculation has to refer back to itself. This really isn't a great thing to solve in SQL. Definitely more of an R/SPSS/Excel thing than it is an RDBMS thing.

Comment: Yeah this is difficult and I mainly came here because I wasn't sure if there was something I was missing.  I spent time on this and nothing obvious hit me.  I can probably use something like Python - Excel, but this would be convenient to just use as a query!

Comment: can you show the actual values please?

Comment: I just added an excel screenshot

Answer (score 3):

This is a hard problem.  Here is a solution using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 1 as n, 1::numeric as x, null::numeric as x_1, null::numeric as x_2
      union all
      select n + 1, 
             (case n + 1 when 2 then 2 when 3 then 5
                   else x + (x - x_2) / 2
              end) as x,
             x as x_1, x_1 as x_2
      from cte 
      where n < 10
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Along with a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c992dcb86451a9d1978150c187f105e1).

The idea is to pivot the historical values that you need in separate columns.  Note that the formula is `x + (x - x_2) / 2` rather than `x_1 + (x_1 - x_3) / 2` because this is using the values from the *previous* row.

Comment: Although don't you have to change the `CAST`s to numeric, so you get decimal results? I modified yours [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=06c8503848e93e0456525a2855ff424f)

Comment: I agree with your answer: This was a tricky problem, and your solution is impressive. :)